# Do we expect to find a dark energy boson?

Tags: dark-energy, bosons

Is dark energy expected to be a force carrying particle that interacts with all forms of matter?

Comment: Be very handy if it interacted with dark matter, do you include that?

Comment: I don't know any of the candidate theories currently running for dark matter or energy. Not sure how they would interact but its a very interesting point to make.

Comment: For dark matter it's the  cold dark matter theory that seems to be main contender https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_dark_matter#Composition   but dark energy I think is a complete mystery , anyway best of luck with an interesting question